# How to design a logic in selenium java to switch between 2 different paths based on question

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to write a logic in selenium-java, where I'm automating a test-taking flow. While taking this test, the test-taker might get either set-1/set-2 in each node which will be randomly assigned by the system.

1. The number of questions in each set may vary
2. Answer data will be passed from an excel(Excel doc attached)

Can anyone please let me know the best approach to switch between set-1/set-2 based on the situation?
Sorry I haven't coded anything yet to share.
I never handled this kind of scenario. Any suggestions would help.

Thank you so much in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Getting data from excel and transferring them to the method**

First, each data set should be placed on separate excel sheet.

[image: Sample of Excel]

Sheet name: Dataset1

Column name: Column1

It takes all values in column(except column name) and then you can use them in any way. In this case TestNG will cycle data in test method.

Second part of solution is data getter from excel.

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class BaseTestProvider {
        Object[][] dataSupplierBase(String path, String sheetname) throws IOException {

        File file = new File(path); //FILE name
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet(sheetname);//SHEET name
        wb.close();
        int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        int lastCellNum = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
        Object[][] obj = new Object[lastRowNum][1];

        for (int i = 0; i < lastRowNum; i++) {
            Map<Object, Object> datamap = new HashMap<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < lastCellNum; j++) {
                datamap.put(sheet.getRow(0).getCell(j).getStringCellValue(), sheet.getRow(i + 1).getCell(j).getStringCellValue());
            }
            obj[i][0] = datamap;
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Third part is data provider of TestNG

```
public class TestCaseDataProvider extends BaseTestProvider {
    @DataProvider(name = "test1")
    public Object[][] dataSupplier1() throws IOException {
        String sheetname = "Dataset1";
        return dataSupplierBase(“path to excel file”, sheetname);
    }
```

Next, using maps to get data from sheet and column.

```
@Test(dataProvider = "test1", dataProviderClass = TestCaseDataProvider.class)
public void testMethod(Map<Object, Object> map) {
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(map.get("Column1")));
    
}
```

So, by changing data provider name, manually or programmatically you can switch between data sets.

**Not solved:** Getting all columns at one pace and manipulating with rows.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable time and comments. I will try this approach and let you know the result.